# how to remove duplicate vectors from a set of vectors in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> S, P, R;
    set<vector<int> > SS;
    S.push_back(9);
    S.push_back(9);
    S.push_back(9);
    P.push_back(656);
    P.push_back(11);
    P.push_back(10);
    R.push_back(10);
    R.push_back(11);
    R.push_back(656);
    SS.insert(R);
    SS.insert(S);
    SS.insert(P);
    set<vector<int> >::iterator itr;
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    for(itr = SS.begin(); itr != SS.end(); itr++) {
        for(i = itr -> begin(); i != itr -> end(); i++) {
            cout<<*i<<" ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Values of vector S and P should be displayed or vector R and S. Use of `set<set<int> >` cannot be used as it will demolish values of vector S.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: What about `set<vector<int>>`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried but something going messy in displying them
set<vector<int> >::iterator itr;
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    for(itr = SS.begin(); itr != SS.end(); itr++) {
        for(i = itr -> begin(); i != itr -> end(); i++) {
            cout<<*i<<" ";
        }

Comment: @anujbajpai Then you should ask a question for help with it making an [mcve]

Comment: @anujbajpai Then please post your display code in the original question, not in the comments.

Comment: @NathanOliver 
for exapmle:-
if certain paths with certain weights are collected and stored in 2D vector.
Then the final 2D vector should contain all distinct paths.

Comment: @anujbajpai Your question as to "*how to remove duplicate vectors from a set** doesn't really make sense, since a `std::set` by definition does *not* store duplicates.  So how do you remove duplicates from a container that has no duplicates?  The `std::set<std::vector<int>>` when given equivalent vectors, both in size and data, will store only one version, exactly as it's supposed to.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie now I think the edit will make it clear for you to understand

Comment: @NathanOliver Now I think the edit will get you the idea

Comment: the above code is showing error

Comment: @anujbajpai Note that your code fails to compile due to you using `iterator i;` instead of `const_iterator i;`.  Other than that, of course those vectors are different.  Different order of values means that the vectors are different.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, I really am a amateur.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I got your both points.just wanted to know const_iterator would make a difference like if something is not meant for write operation, only read stuff can be carried out, so howcome did this made a difference in the above problem ?

Comment: The difference is that `const_iterator` is the only iterator you can use for the `std::set`'s data.  You cannot change the data that the `std::set` has, else you would potentially corrupt the `std::set`'s structure itself.  You must be using an old compiler if it accepted an `iterator` and not `const_iterator`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using initial_vector = std::vector<int>;
using vector_of_vecs = std::vector<initial_vector>;

template<class...Args>
vector_of_vecs uniqify(Args&&...args)
{
    // build a temporary vector of vectors
    vector_of_vecs result { args... };

    // sort it. std::unique requires the vector to be sorted
    sort(result.begin(), result.end());

    // erase all items that are not unique.
    result.erase(std::unique(result.begin(),
                             result.end()),
                 result.end());

    // return the result
    return result;
}


auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<int> A, B, C;
    A = {2, 4, 5};
    B = {2, 2, 2};
    C = {2, 4, 5};

    // note: to avoid copies, simply move the vectors into uniquify
    auto uv = uniqify(std::move(A), std::move(B), std::move(C));

    // or preserve the source vectors and force copies if you wish
    //auto uv = uniqify(A, B, C);

    // uv is now a vector of unique vectors.

    // print out our vector of unique vectors
    for(const auto& i : uv){
        cout << '[';
        auto sep = " ";
        for (const auto& j : i) {
            cout << sep << j;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        cout << " ]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected result:

```
[ 2, 2, 2 ]
[ 2, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a set of multisets.  A multiset is like a vector, but sorted, so P and R (converted to multisets) would be equal.

```
set<multiset<int> > SS;
....
SS.insert(multiset(R.begin(), R.end());
SS.insert(multiset(S.begin(), S.end());
SS.insert(multiset(P.begin(), P.end());
```